# Step in proof that $Y=aX+b\Rightarrow$ corr$[X,Y]=\pm 1$

Tags: probability, integration

I read through the proof 2.3 [here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ecroot/3225/rho_notes.pdf), which shows that if  $Y=\lambda_1 X+\lambda_2$, then corr$[X,Y]=\pm 1$.

The proof uses that $\mu_Y = \lambda_1 \mu_X+\lambda_2$.

I have difficulty to show this relationship between $\mu_Y$ and $\mu_X$.

Starting with the defintion of $\mu_Y$:

$$\mu_Y = \int yp_Y(y) dy$$

... using the relationship between $X$ and $Y$, and the probability distribution defined on $X$:

$$=\int y p_X\left(\frac{y-\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right) dy$$

... change of variable ($y=\phi(x)=\lambda_1 x+\lambda_2$) should result in:

$$=\int (\lambda_1 x+\lambda_2) p_X(x) \phi'(x) dx$$

$$=\int (\lambda_1 x+\lambda_2) p_X(x) \lambda_1 dx$$

$$=\lambda_1 (\lambda_1 \mu_X+\lambda_2) \neq (\lambda_1 \mu_X+\lambda_2)$$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to compute all that, it's enough to know that the expectation is a linear operator, hence $E(aX+b) = a E(X) +b$.

Regarding your procedure: if $Y=a X + b$, the densities are related by

$$ f_Y(y) = \frac{f_X((y-b)/a)}{|a|}$$

Comment: Even using the linearity of the expectation, I'm still a bit puzzled. By linearity one has $E_Y[Y] = E_Y[aX+b] = a E_Y[X] + b$ -- but this is still the expectation under Y ... how does one go from there without integrals+change of variables?

Comment: $E(Y)$ is the expectation of $Y$, there is not such a thing as "expectation of $Y$ under $Y$" vs "expectation of $Y$ under $X$"

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this without writing any integrals, just using properties of expectation. Note first that $E[Y]=aE[X]+b$ so:

\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(X,Y) & = E[(X-E[X])(aX+b-aE[X]-b)] \\
& =E[(X-E[X])(aX-aE[X])] \\
& =aE[(X-E[X])(X-E[X])] = a \text{Var}(X)
\end{align*}

We also know that $\text{Var}(aX+b)=a^2 \text{Var}(X)$, so $\sqrt{\text{Var}(X) \text{Var}(Y)} = |a| \text{Var}(X)$. Finally the correlation coefficient is the ratio of these two, which is $\frac{a}{|a|}=\text{sign}(a)$ (provided $a \neq 0$). When $a=0$ the correlation naively takes the indeterminate form $0/0$, so there is more to be said in that case.

Comment: Sorry if that was not clear - my question is about how one can show that $E[Y]=a E[X]+b$, which is used in the proof.

Comment: @benroth Suppose $S$ is a simple function (a random variable that takes on only finitely many values with positive probability). Then by definition $E[S]=\sum_{i=1}^n s_i P(S=s_i)$. So here $E[aS+b]=aE[S]+b$ comes simply from algebra. Any nonnegative random variable $X$ is an almost sure monotone limit of simple functions $S_n$, and we define $E[X]$ to be $\lim_{n \to \infty} E[S_n]$. Since $aS_n + b$ converges to $aX+b$ almost surely (check this), the property is preserved in the limit.

Comment: @benroth (Cont.) Now for a general random variable $Y$, provided $E[|Y|]<\infty$ (in the sense above), we define $E[Y]=E[Y^+]-E[Y^-]$, where $Y^+$ is the positive part of $Y$ and $Y^-$ is the negative part of $Y$. Since the property held for the positive and negative parts separately, algebra shows that it holds for their difference.